# OpenShift and Istio Gateway traffic configuration in order to access using an external a domain

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, istio

After deploying Istio 1.1.2 on OpenShift there is an istio-ingressgateway route with its associated service and pod.

I have successfully used that ingress gateway to access an application, configuring a Gateway and a VirtualService using * as hosts.

However I would like to configure a domain, e.g insuranceinc.es, to access the application. According to the documentation I have this Istio config:

**Gateway:**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: insuranceinc-gateway
  namespace: istio-insuranceinc
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "insuranceinc.es"
```

**VirtualService**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: insuranceinc
  namespace: istio-insuranceinc
spec:
  hosts:
    - insuranceinc.es
  gateways:
    - insuranceinc-gateway
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: insuranceinc-web
            port:
              number: 8080
```

If I make this curl invocation...

`curl http://istio-ingressgateway-istio-system.apps.mycluster.com/login`

... I can see a 404 error in the ingress-gateway pod:

```
[2019-04-12T15:27:51.765Z] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404 NR "-" 0 0 1 - "xxx" "curl/7.54.0" "xxx" "istio-ingressgateway-istio-system.apps.mycluster.com" "-" - - xxx -
```

This makes sense since it isn't comming from an insuranceinc.es host. So I change the curl to send a `Host: insuranceinc.es` header:

`curl -H "Host: insuranceinc.es"  http://istio-ingressgateway-istio-system.apps.mycluster.com/login`

Now I am getting a 503 error and there are no logs in the istio-ingressgateway pod.

> ## Application is not available
>
> The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.

This means the request hasn't been processed by that istio-ingressgateway route->service->poc.

Since it is an `Openshift Route` it must be needing a Host header containing the route host `istio-ingressgateway-istio-system.apps.mycluster.com`. In fact if I send `curl -H "Host: istio-ingressgateway-istio-system.apps.mycluster.com"  http://istio-ingressgateway-istio-system.apps.mycluster.com/login` it is processed by the istio ingress gateway returning a 404.

So, how can I send my Host insuranceinc.es header and also reach the istio ingress gateway (which is actually an OpenShift route)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an openshift route in the istio-system namespace to relate to the hostname you created.

For example:

```
oc -n istio-system get routes
NAME              HOST/PORT                                            PATH      SERVICES               PORT      TERMINATION   WILDCARD
gateway1-lvlfn    insuranceinc.es                                                istio-ingressgateway   <all>                   None
```

Comment: Thank you @Chris, this is something that was missing from the documentation but is required.